# Shell globbing negation doesn't work in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm currently confused why shell globbing in terminal works with negation but shows an error when running in bash.

Take the commands executed in the terminal below, which shows all js files within the `./HTML` directory except for js files that ends with `.bundle.js`.

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ ls ./HTML/**/!(*.bundle).js
```

The command above works perfectly, now let's put it in a bash file

**list-js.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar
ls ./HTML/**/!(*.bundle).js
```

Executing it in a terminal:

```
$ bash list-js.sh
list-js.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
list-js.sh: line 4: `ls ./HTML/**/!(*.bundle).js'
```

As you can see, it shows a syntax error.

Comment: You forgot `shopt -s globstar` in your script

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I edited the script, forgot to add the `shopt -s globstar`. I'm pretty sure that wasn't the problem.

Comment: Then you have to enable another option. extglob perhaps?

Comment: @JulienLopez definitely not :)

Comment: @ryeballar Saw your comment afterwards. :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`globstar` only enables the `**` pattern. The `extglob` option allows `!(...)`. Somewhere in your interactive shell, that has already been enabled (perhaps in your `.bashrc`, perhaps you typed `shopt -s extglob` earlier). However, it needs to be enabled explicitly in your script, since such settings are not inherited from the shell that starts the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar extglob
ls ./HTML/**/!(*.bundle).js
```

(As an aside, `**` without `globstar` does not cause a syntax error because it is treated simply as two adjacent `*`s, the second one being redundant.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I already assumed that `extglob` was already enabled since it's already enabled in my terminal without me enabling it. I guess I had a script somewhere on my `.bashrc` that enables it inherently.

Comment: Not really pertinent here, but starting with `bash` 4.1, there is a compile-time option to make `extglob` on by default, and it is always enabled temporarily inside `[[ ... ]]` for use with `==` and `!=`.